# usb mouse stops working after run the os in ubuntu

Tags: usb, mouse

completely new to Ubuntu, but getting away from windows and mac. Basically my USB wired mouse stops working after a few second being on, I've tried with other computers and the mouse worked fine, this has only started to occur in past week or so, I've tried following tips etc on here & youtube and the longest I've had out of it is about ten minutes without opening any programs. Using 14.04 if that helps, just need someone to say "yeah, just do this..." If you need me to send over tech details, let me know how, as it's a tadge different from windows!

Comment: Have you tried *other* mouses on this computer?

Comment: yes, but the same problem occur

Answer (score 0):

There is a big story behind mouse freezes in ubuntu. First, here is a workaround that might help:

```
sudo rmmod psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

or

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Second, you can file a bug on launchpad, and it might get fixed in the future. Like this one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpi-support/+bug/804109